# ActionController::ParamaterMissing while running test. From Chapter 7 of Hartl's Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

Currently doing Hartl's (updated) Tutorial and I'm stuck at the end of Chapter 7 [7.5.3 to be specific, Production Deployment].

I'm running a test and getting the following error:

```
1) Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_invalid_signup_information:
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: user
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:24:in `user_params'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:12:in `create'
test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'


2) Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information:
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: user
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:24:in `user_params'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:12:in `create'
test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
       redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
 end
```

**users_signup_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "",
                                         email: "user@invalid",
                                         password:              "foo",
                                         password_confirmation: "bar" } }
                                         end
                                         end                                                              


  test "valid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "Example User",
                                         email: "user@example.com",
                                         password:              "password",
                                         password_confirmation: "password" } }
    end
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
  end
end
```

Comment: What version of Rails and of RSpec do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the `post` (and the other HTTP request methods) has change between Rails 4 and Rails 5.

So send a `user` param in Rails 4 use this:

```
post user_path, { user: { name: 'foo' } }
```

Whereas in Rails 5 use this:

```
post user_path, params: { user: { name: 'foo' } }
```

Hartl's Rails Tutorial was updated to Rails 5 recently. But I guess you are still running Rails 4. That means: remove nesting of the params or update your app to Rails 5.

Comment: This clarified it. I was scratching my head here. I'm using Rails 4.2.6 and I've noticed there are a few differences in Hartl's current tutorial (Rails 5 uses "rails" instead of "rake" for example), thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have params, instead of user.

**Change this:**

```
 params: { name:  "", 
                      email: "user@invalid",
                      password: "foo",
                      password_confirmation: "bar" } }
       end
   end
```

**to this:**

```
  user: { name:  "", 
                          email: "user@invalid",
                          password: "foo",
                          password_confirmation: "bar" } }
          end
       end
```

Comment: Fixed! Thanks Marv.